# NaN polluting max() of two object DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I take the max of two columns of floats, even if some are NaN, the result is fairly predictable:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
                       "b": [3, 2, float("nan"), 9]})
>>> df
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  9.0
>>> df.dtypes
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
>>> df[["a", "b"]].max(axis=1)
0    3.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    9.0
dtype: float64
```

though I'm not sure why the max of 3.0 and NaN isn't NaN.

If, however, the columns contain non-float types (strings in this example), NaN seems to totally pollute the result:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["1", "2", "3", "4"], 
                       "b": ["3", "2", float("nan"), "9"]})
>>> df
   a    b
0  1    3
1  2    2
2  3  NaN
3  4    9
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
>>> df[["a", "b"]].max(axis=1)
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I expected the output of the max() call would be 3, 2, NaN, 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell pandas what to include in taking [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html), but only `float`, `int`, and `boolean` are valid types. No implicit conversion of strings to numeric types is done, so in `df` an element like `"3"` is not included in taking the maximum. The only numeric value is `NaN` which is thus returned.

To get the expected result you need first to convert the strings to a numeric type, e.g.,

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

and then provide `skipna=False` to include the `NaN`:

```
df.max(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have used more obviously non-numeric strings in my example. I was just converting my float-y example to strings. In my actual problem, I don't have strings which could be converted to floats.

Comment: @smontanaro I may still not get the problem but with non-numeric strings your expected output would be just `NaN`? This should also be achieved by `skipna=False`.

Comment: @smontanaro In the example `df` with numeric values stored as strings and `skipna=False` only `NaN`s are returned. Maybe you can try to adapt your example so that your problem is reproducible?

Comment: >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "b": ["c", "b", float("nan"), "j"]})
    >>> df.dtypes
    a    object
    b    object
    dtype: object
    >>> df[["a", "b"]].max(axis=1, skipna=False)
    0   NaN
    1   NaN
    2   NaN
    3   NaN
    dtype: float64

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't figure out how to properly embed a code snippet in a comment.

Comment: @smontanaro The returned value consists only of `NaN`s. What should it be in your opinion? (You can format inline code by enclosing text with backticks `.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181432/discussion-between-smontanaro-and-gofvonx).